# Can data in a rooted tree be processed in parallel?

Tags: trees, parallelism, big-data

I have data that is structured like the following:

```
users:

id | name  | parent_id
1  | Bob   | NULL
2  | Jan   | 1
3  | Mat   | 2
4  | Irene | 2
5  | Ellie | 2
6  | Laura | 5
7  | Uma   | 6

user_sales:

user_id | sales_period | total_volume | total_revenue | ....
    1   |  Jan-2017    |  1000        |   56000
    1   |  Feb-2017    |  1500        |   65000
    2   |  Jan-2017    |  650         |   45500
    5   |  Jan-2017    |  800         |   49005
    6   |  Jan-2017    |  1000        |   56000

add a bunch more tables that use the core users tree structure...
```

We have client databases ranging in size from ~60GB to ~1TB and infinitely scaling database servers to support large ETL operations isn't an option. In researching solutions, it looks like our best bet would be to find a way to employ parallel processing but a fundamental question we keep coming back to is whether you can use parallel processing when everything requires traversing a tree structure like we have?

Can anyone answer whether we can process a rooted tree data structure in parallel and if so, do you have suggestions on how it should be done?

Comment: it depends a bit on what you want to do.  For many queries you wouldn't care if you have a tree structure or not (for example calculate total_revenue regardless of userid). For others you could employ parallelism by searching though each leaf of the tree at the same time (for example process Mat, Irene and Ellie in parallel using worker threads)

Comment: @Batavia Assume that I'm not trying to run aggregates, the more frequent operations seem to be filtering and sorting. Seems like filtering should be able to be done in parallel.